# Rave Report - как сделать простой (самый обычный) счётчик в таблице?

Tags: mysql, delphi, delphi-xe, ravereport

Допустим первая строка в таблице - 1
Вторая - 2. Аля rowcount.
Передавать параметрами из самого приложения, это понятно, можно. Но запрос-то формируется из самого репорта. Писать параллельный запрос на количество строк в выборке из Delphi, как-то не есть правильно.
Но я, почему-то, думаю, что и в самом Rave Raport есть такой механизм. Ведь он очень громоздкий какой-то. Должно быть в нём такое где-то.

Answer (score 1):

Как то так на примере номера строки, немножко не то но все же:

```
// Sample event that "increments" a parameter named "LineCount"
{ Event for DataTextCount1.OnGetText }
function DataTextCount1_OnGetText(Self: TRaveDataText; var Value: string);
var
  iCount: Integer;
  sCount: String;
begin
  iCount := StrToInt(RaveProject.GetParam('LineCount'));
  sCount := IntToStr(iCount + 1);
  Value := sCount;
  RaveProject.SetParam('LineCount', sCount);
end;
```

Пример взят [тут](https://www.nevrona.com/download/RaveDevGuide.pdf) (стр. 32 п 2.6.1)